# How to I cast data frame with more than 3 columns in R?

Tags: r, casting, reshape, tidyr, reshape2

Importing from an Access database, I have data that look similar to this:

```
p <- data.frame(SurvDate = as.Date(c('2018-11-1','2018-11-1','2018-11-1',
                                     '2018-11-3', '2018-11-3')), 
                Area = c('AF','BB','CT', 'DF', 'BB'), 
                pCount = c(6, 3, 0, 12, 32), 
                ObsTime = c('8:51','8:59','9:13', '9:24', '9:30'), 
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to cast my data with Rows as SurvDate and columns to be Areas (values as pCount) and ObsTime columns next to each Area with value ObsTime.

Example:

```
n <- data.frame(SurvDate = as.Date(c('2018-11-1','2018-11-3')), 
                AF = c(6, NA), 
                TimeAF = c('8:51', NA), 
                BB = c(3, 32), 
                TimeBB = c('8:59', '9:30'), 
                CT = c(0, NA), 
                TimeCT = c(NA, '9:13'), 
                DF = c(NA,12), 
                TimeDF = c(NA, '9:24'))
```

I've tried variations on this theme, but can't get time to work.

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(p, SurvDate+ObsTime ~ Area)
```

Comment: If you're open to non `dcast` solutions, this is just a reshape to wide - `reshape(p, idvar="SurvDate", timevar="Area", direction="wide")`

Comment: Do you know how many columns there will need to be?

Comment: There will be several other columns too that are both character, numbers, and factors.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `tidyverse` tools. Note that the output is not the same as your expected output, because it seems like you didn't put the values for  CT in the right place (values spread across two dates). Approach is to `unite` the values so we have a single key-value pair to `spread`, and then separate out the columns again with `mutate_at`. We could also have used `separate` multiple times, though this would become unwieldy with too many `Area`s.

```r
SurvDate <- as.Date(c('2018-11-1','2018-11-1','2018-11-1', '2018-11-3', '2018-11-3'))
Area <- c('AF','BB','CT', 'DF', 'BB')
People <- c(6, 3, 0, 12, 32)
ObsTime <- (c('8:51','8:59','9:13', '9:24', '9:30'))
p <- data.frame(SurvDate, Area, People, ObsTime, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(tidyverse)
p %>%
  unite(vals, People, ObsTime) %>%
  spread(Area, vals) %>%
  mutate_at(
    .vars = vars(-SurvDate),
    .funs = funs(
      Time = str_extract(., "(?<=_).*$"),
      Area = str_extract(., "^.*(?=_)")
    )
  ) %>%
  filter(!is.na(SurvDate)) %>%
  select(SurvDate,  matches("_")) %>%
  select(SurvDate, order(colnames(.)))
#>     SurvDate AF_Area AF_Time BB_Area BB_Time CT_Area CT_Time DF_Area
#> 1 2018-11-01       6    8:51       3    8:59       0    9:13    <NA>
#> 2 2018-11-03    <NA>    <NA>      32    9:30    <NA>    <NA>      12
#>   DF_Time
#> 1    <NA>
#> 2    9:24
```

Created on 2018-04-30 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: These areas will be sampled at several dates, but not every date sampled. The code you listed above loses that BB information for the second date as you mentioned.

Comment: Had an extra line break causing NA last date, it's fixed now.